# For what do you use a Vynoran priest alt while grinding religion up to a useful level?

Tags: wurm-online

So, I recently promoted an alt to a priest of Vynora.  I knew there were a bunch of things I couldn't do any more but I failed to really grasp the enormity of this list.  So now he basically stays home and tends the farm, blesses the horses and prays at the altar.

Is there anything else I might be missing to make him useful around the homestead?

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty much it, Mine used to farm on a little homestead dead of the main base (I was on the blacklight side)

*(Please note I havent had a preist or played wurm scince beta days)
On another note, Im amazed to see a wurm question pop up,

Comment: For what it's worth, a lot has changed in five years -- even if the core of the game is the same.  I'll hold out hope for a more currently-informed answer.  :)